# VB.NET - Snake? Game - Development

Tags: vb.net

I am currently in the process of making a snake game using VB.NET... I was just wanting to gather ideas on how to do the body of the snake...

Currently I have a class called SnakeBody which contains the following code:

```
Public Class SnakeBody
    Dim yCoord As Integer
    Dim xCoord As Integer
    Dim body As PictureBox
End Class
```

I guess what I am asking is if `Dim body As PictureBox` a logical thing to put in my class. As in, I am not sure if that is the correct thing to do? To create the actual body of the snake I will have an array of these SnakeBody objects.

If `'Dim body As PictureBox is valid How do I reproduce the same picturebox everytime my snake eats something?

I hop this makes sense... Thanks Alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is okay but it is not going to work well in practice.  PictureBox is a window, when snakes overlap each other, you'll obscure part of them with a rectangle.  You'll essentially see one snake in a rectangle with bits of other snakes peeking out past that rectangle.

Use the form's Paint event to draw the snakes, don't use a control.

Comment: Agreed, paint the snake, if you look back to the original game the snake was just pixels that would add another to the back when you ate another pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Winforms. Use vb.net and silverlight, you can design a template for the snake , you have silverlights sophisticated built in animation. It will be so much easier and better and it will run on a PC and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

actually i don't know how to add a cube when the snake eat something

try to use System.drawing.graphics to draw cubes ( parts of the snake ) : it's a bit easier

if you want to make the snake moving you should make a script based on this :

**REMEMBER : THIS IS ONLY A DIMOSTRATION OF WHAT HAVE THE CODE TO DO :**

```
Dim CubeSelected as integer = 1 ' Selected cube

loop {

 if right_key_pressed{

 ' You have to make this command : cube(number of the cube , direction)

cube(CubeSelected,right) ' Change the selected cube direction 

MoveSelect = MoveSelect + 1 ' Select the next cube
Threading.Thread.Sleep(500) ' Wait 
   }

}
```

if you press the right key , the cubes will change the direction one for time . 
**So the snake will make a curve and proceed to the right direction**

it's a little more complicated actually , but i hope it helps